# Method to find all server controls of a page in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, findcontrol

Is there some generic method to find all server controls of a page in asp.net webforms?

I'm using this method to do that, but it is not finding the controls inside an asp:Repeater:

```
private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, List<T> resultCollection) where T : Control
{
     foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
     {
         if (control is T)
             resultCollection.Add((T)control);

         if (control.HasControls())
             GetControlList(control.Controls, resultCollection);
     }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Has `DataBind()` been called on the repeater? If not, the repeater's `Controls` collection won't be populated.

Comment: Your method is correct - I use a similar one myself a lot. Michael Liu is correct - the repeater is probably not data bound yet.

Comment: It was the problem. My repeater was filled after the find controns methos execution. Thanks to all!